How to properly export to fbx or obj, for unity
I made a house, I downloaded some materials. I need a house in the Unity engine. When sending materials, there was no house separately; there are also particles, too. How to do everything correctly in Blender so that you can transfer it to Unity without problems?

Just to clarify, you've having trouble exporting your file?

To export an .fbx file out of Blender, first click File > External Data > Automatically Pack Resources. Then select File > Export > FBX (.fbx).
The export file menu will pop up. On the right side of the menu, click Limit To and check the box that says Selected Objects. Then change the Path Mode dropdown from Auto to Copy and click the little icon of a box next to the Copy option. Then click Export. Your file should render as an .fbx.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures
